# Why are my array movie clips getting harder to click when they get faster?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a game where insects come down from the top of the screen, and the user must kill them. The insects are in an array. Each time the user kills them, the score goes up..after a while the insects get faster and faster. When they get faster, some of them don't get killed when you click them. You have to click multiple times for them to die. I want them to get killed in one click, but this isn't working when they get faster!

```
  function makeEnemies():void
   {
var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
if (chance <=  + level)
{


    //Make sure a Library item linkage is set to Enemy...
    tempEnemy = new Enemy();
    //Math.random(); gets a random number from 0.0-1.0
    tempEnemy.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
    addChild(tempEnemy);
    enemies.push(tempEnemy);
    tempEnemy.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
}
}


function moveEnemies():void
{
var tempEnemy:MovieClip;


for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
     tempEnemy=enemies[i];
if (tempEnemy.dead) 
{
    score++;
    score++;
    roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
    enemies.splice(i,1);
} 



     else // Enemy is still alive and moving across the screen
    {
        //rotate the enemy between 10-5 degrees
        tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
        //Find the rotation and move the x position that direction
        tempEnemy.x -=  (Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
        tempEnemy.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
        if (tempEnemy.x < 10)
        {
            tempEnemy.x = 11;
        }
        if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
        {
             tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
        }
        if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
        {
            removeEnemy(i);

            lives--;
            roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
        }
    }
}
}

function removeEnemy(id:int)
{

removeChild(enemies[id]);
enemies.splice(id,1);
}
```

There is also code inside the insect.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.motion.Animator;
import flash.events.*;
play();
var MainTimeLine = MovieClip(root);
var mysound:squish = new squish(); 
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kill);
this.dead = false;

function kill(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
this.dead=true;
mouseChildren=false
mysound.play();
gotoAndPlay(21);
this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kill);
flash.utils.setTimeout(removeSelf,2000);

}

function removeSelf():void
{
this.parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

Comment: I'd suspect a memory leak. Do the enemies contain any code? I don't see anything where you're listening for a click on them. What does your removeEnemy() function look like?

Comment: Hmm, let me post in the question

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't remove an enermy from the array while iterating it.
You make *enemies.splice(i,1);* in your loop iterating from enemies.length to 0. While you changing your array size, you don't adjust the loop condition.

Comment: I have the enemies.splice, but I don't understand where I should add another code for the lag to disappear. I mean the game works perfect, it's just that when they get faster it becomes harder to click

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue might be that you are reusing your insects, maybe pooling them. If you do this, you need to make sure that you are adding the eventListener for the click again when recycling.

If you are adding the listener in the constructor, that will only execute when the insect is created, not when you recycle him.

Comment: It sounds like from your comments and code that you don't have an Insect class, but the code is inside the library symbol - on it's timeline. I suspect that there is more code that we don't see, that plays into this issue and possibly others.  For example a run-time error can cause lines that we "assume" are executing, to not execute. Are you getting any runtime errors ?

Comment: Yes, the code is inside the insect in the library. I am not getting any run time errors, and the code is working correctly, but when the insects get faster the accuracy of click gets harder, even when I do click on them

Comment: I really can't help you anymore without seeing the actual .fla The process we are currently using is not efficient as it's likely something we don't see that is the primary issue. For example, I don't even know if you have code on other frames for that Insect. There's numerous unknowns that could cause problems. I have no idea what is on frame 21 of that insect. Post the .fla somewhere. Otherwise, it's amounting to programming charades here.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the setTimeOut(), which is causing a memory leak. Using a timer is much safer, but if you *must* use it, keep a reference to the call and clear it when you no longer need it.

Also, the code you posted doesn't show where you're adding a listener to MainTimeline or parent, but if you are you need to remove that as well before the insect can be garbage collected.